# difference between event loop in nodeja and event loop in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, event-loop

In browser ,when we run web application ,then event loop starts that monitor that tab and handles asynchronous tasks. Every tab has its own event loop and every tab is process in browser.

I am confused in node.js event loop architecture.

Suppose I have a node.js app and I deploy it on server. When I make a request my request will start node.js process and one event loop is dedicated to that process I.e. (It will handle all timer, tick all the asynchronous tasks and behavior).

When I make one more request, it will start one more node.js process of my app and one more event loop is attached with it ...taking analogy from browser tabs (every tab is a separate process and has its own event loop).
Am I right or I am missing anything? And please don't provide youtube link for watching event loop video. My primary purpose is to clear my mental model of node.js.

Answer (score 0):

When you run an application using nodejs a single process is started, that spawns a thread pool for handling io.

There is a single event loop that receives data from the io threads in response to requests. If the event loop is blocked then requests will queue until it can receive them.

It uses the libuv library to accomplish this https://github.com/libuv/libuv

Answer (score 0):

> When i make a request my request will start nodejs process and one event loop is dedicated to that process ie( it will handle all timer ,tick,all the asynchronous taks and behaviour). When I make one more request ,it will start one more nodejs process of my app and one more event loop is attached with it ...taking analogy from browser tabs(every tab is a separate process and has its own event loop).

No, not unless you have a setup that's doing that for you. Node.js doesn't do that.

When you start a Node.js-based web server, a *single* process with a *single* event loop serviced by a single thread is started. [More here in the Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/). The way that Node.js handles multiple concurrent requests is by using asynchronous I/O. The thread can start a write operation to respond to one request, start a read operation to read another equestion, and those operations (neither of which uses the JavaScript thread [mostly) run in parallel.

If you have long-running JavaScript tasks that your Node.js server has to do in response to requests, you can offload those to [workers](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/worker_threads.html).

Comment: server..this is where i am confused...I work in front end..i am not able to visualize the complete flow of requests and response.you said 'Node.js-based web server' ,suppose i have two seaparate node js app ,it means we have two node process ,it means context switching will occur and one node process will have to wait while one is executing .Suppose in same machine i deploy tomcat server and java app..beacuse server needs port ,it means they are also process ,now is there will be any context switching at server level also..?

Comment: think of each node.js app like a browser tab, but with a lot of people clicking the mouse...

Answer (score 0):

Both Node.js and browsers use an event loop to handle asynchronous operations, but there are key differences in their capabilities and use-cases. Here's a breakdown of how the event loops in Node.js and browsers differ:

Node.js Event Loop

1. Environment: Server-side

2.Built On: Built on top of the libuv library, which provides the underlying event loop.

3.Task Queues: Multiple queues (timers, I/O, immediate, close events) to handle various types of tasks.

4.I/O-bound: Optimized for I/O-bound operations and well-suited for networking applications.

5.Module Support: Provides native modules (like fs for file system access, http for HTTP servers, and so on) that can be non-blocking and utilize the event loop effectively.

Browser Event Loop

1.Environment: Client-side

2.Built On: Built into the browser itself, usually on top of underlying OS capabilities.

3.Task Queues: Single task queue but can handle setTimeout, setInterval, and UI rendering tasks
.
4.UI-bound: Optimized for UI updates and animations.

5.Module Support: Lacks native modules for I/O operations like file system access but can perform tasks like HTTP requests through APIs like XMLHttpRequest and Fetch, which also use the event loop.

6.Background Threads: Can offload work to Web Workers but can't directly access DOM or other web APIs.